# If I don't have tag wiki editing privileges, I shouldn't be asked to approve the edit I just did, eh?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I edited the Tag Wiki to insert some info about InDesign. Not having edit privileges in the Tag Wiki, I got the expected message that the edit would have to be approved. I was surprised, then, when the site popped up an "Approve Tag Wiki Edit" request, and it turned out to be the edit I'd just done.

I didn't click the approval button, since that just didn't seem like the thing to do, so I don't know if the site logic would have blocked it. But it shouldn't have shown up in the first place, right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suggest edits, and approve them, but not your own. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89635/155668) on MSO.

Comment: Yup. It struck me as odd that they showed up in my status bar at all.